# OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow - XMLHttpRequest CORS and SameSite error and Gack

Tags: oauth2, chat, gack, jwt, cors

[image]
We are implamenting a chatbot using the OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow and see the above errors in the browser client degugger. We already have a valid access token and the origin has already been white-listed in SalesForce. Has anyone else ran across these errors?

Comment: When I look at the response to GET /2020myBCUKnowledge/embeddedService/sidebarApp.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT HTTP/1.1 using Fiddler I see there is actually an decode response "*/{"message":"An internal server error has occurred\nError ID: 628246039-202345 (924250524)"}/*ERROR*/" . With a little googling I've found this is known to Salesforce Support as a "Gack". Any idea what the particular code I received means?

Comment: My assumption is the Gack error is preventing the full responce from being generated so the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is never returned on the responce. Is this a valid assumption?

Comment: I suggest that you raise a support case so support can investigate it.

Comment: Also, more details with code will help to debug it further

Comment: One addtional note. I have read the the callback URL (Connected App) field is not needed fro the JWT flow. Is this correct?

Comment: That’s correct redirect or callback makes no sense! Can you reach out to me via my email mohith.shrivastava@salesforce.com so I can assist you?

Comment: Thank you Mohith. We are working with a third party who is handling the Salesforce Connected app/setup. I have access to chatbot snippet and token creation code only. They have a case created with Salesforce. At Salesforces’ advice they recently added the Integration User to the Site (Community). We now see a different error below using Fiddler:
"{"event":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:invalidSession","attributes":{"values":{}},"eventDef":{"descriptor":"markup://aura:invalidSession","t":"APPLICATION","xs":"I","a":{"newToken":["newToken","aura://String","I",false]}}},"exceptionEvent":true}"

Comment: We have this issue resolved. It was one of the Orgwide settings that needed to be enabled - Setup > Security > Session Settings

- Activate the Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated check box.

Answer (score 1):

To Summerize what fixed this issue for us:

- We added the Integration User to the Site (Community).
- Selected the [Orgwide session setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_authentication.htm#lightning_out_authentication) - Setup > Security > Session Settings - "Activate the Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated"